# jquery combobox not pulling data with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, combobox

I'm using the jQuery combobox widget which works fine, but is causing some issues when added dynamically.

**What should happen**

- Visitor uses the combobox to filter/select valid users to add to a
  list.
- The list has no max number of users that can be added.
- There's a [+] toggle button at the end of each user field that allows the Visitor to add another user to the list.
- Clicking the button makes an ajax call to add more users to the list, allowing there to be no limit to the max number of users.
- Initially, 10 user fields are loaded on screen, and then when they click the [+] button towards the end, the ajax call adds another 10 to the list.

**What's Happening**

When the form with the list of users is submitted, the users from the initial 10 fields appear fine, but any fields added as part of the ajax call are returned as empty.

Here's the code:

**combobox:**

```
  (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        var input,
          that = this,
          wasOpen = false,
          select = this.element.hide(),
          selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
          wrapper = this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
            .addClass( "ui-combobox" )
            .insertAfter( select );

        function removeIfInvalid( element ) {
          var value = $( element ).val(),
            matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( value ) + "$", "i" ),
            valid = false;
          select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
            if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
              this.selected = valid = true;
              return false;
            }
          });

          if ( !valid ) {

          }
        }

        input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .addClass( "ui-state-default ui-combobox-input " )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
              var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
              response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                var text = $( this ).text();
                if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                  return {
                    label: text.replace(
                      new RegExp(
                        "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                        $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                        ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                      ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                    value: text,
                    option: this
                  };
              }) );
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
              ui.item.option.selected = true;
              that._trigger( "selected", event, {
                item: ui.item.option
              });

            },
            change: function( event, ui ) {
              if ( !ui.item ) {
               removeIfInvalid( this );
              }
            }
          })
          .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

        input.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
          return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };

        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          // .tooltip()
          .appendTo( wrapper )
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();

            // close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }

            // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });

       //  input.tooltip({
       // //  tooltipClass: "tool_toplft"
       //  });
      },

      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );
```

**ajax code:**

```
$('body').on('click','.add_usr', function(){

    if($('.box.noshow').length == 3){
        $(this).fadeOut(800);
        var count = parseInt($(this).attr('data-ctr')) +1;
        $.post('/base/process.php', {action: 'team_add_usr_select', 'count': count}, function(data){
            $('.box:last').after(data.output);

        });

    }
        $('.box.noshow').first().fadeIn(800).removeClass('noshow');
        $('.box').children('select').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.box.noshow').each(function(){
            $(this).children('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
        $('.add_usr').css('display','none');
        $('.box:visible').last().children('.add_usr').css('display','inline-block');

        if($('.box:visible').length > 1){
            $('.del_usr').css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
    return false;
```

});

Again, the combobox is working correctly, but when I submit the form, the fields are present but blank.

**UPDATE**

`data` outputs an object with the details for me, including the original form information.Here's an example of the output:

```
form: Object
form: "team_add"
id_leader: "1"
id_team: ""
team_name: "test"
usr: Object
    1: "1"
    2: "13"
    3: "521"
    4: "533"
    5: "2"
    6: "3"
    7: "816"
```

This example was sent with 12 users added. The new fields are added to the form after entry #7 is filled and clicked. Also, I've noticed in this instance it stopped showing additional fields. Previously when testing, it would list `8: ""`. Now I'm more confused.

Comment: Does `data` inside successful ajax callback have anything?

Comment: Yes. `data` returns an object where i've output the original form data and can see that it has the input, with the exception of the newly added fields. I've just rechecked it to add detail above.

Comment: Hmm, I still can't understand what does `data.output` contain? Is it some valid html markup? Did you look at your new html markup after ajax call was made?

Comment: sry I wasn't clear however, I've now solved the issue thanks to going back through it again to try and clarify! Thanks for the help Ilya Luzyanin!!